# Special Variety of x in math mode

Tags: math-mode

I am trying to find a command for the style of x in math mode the formula below. It looks a little bit like Chi but it's actually x.

I've searched some references for LaTex math symbols and was unable to find a command.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: But your image is taken from the web? Peraphs is it Cambria-Math?

Comment: @Sebastiano, yes it's typeset from another program (in an academic journal), but I'm wondering if a similar variety of x exists in latex

Comment: latex does not control the shapes of letters, that is just font choice, if you have access to a pdf or html version of that document you can see what fonts it uses, but basically that is just `$n_2m_2+x_2$` the font choice is just that, same as any other choice of font

Comment: Similar x I have seen with euler package. But I think that this font is extern to the LaTeX usual fonts. I totally accept with the David Carlisle's comment.